# Where can I find material that introduces homotopy (co)invariants?

Tags: homotopy-theory, at.algebraic-topology

Thanks for pointing out any reference.

Comment: Is there a specific setting in which you want to study homotopy (co)invariants?  For example, do you have in mind a question about topological spaces, or complexes of vector spaces?  Are you looking for an abstract homotopy-theoretic treatment?

Comment: In Costello's work "The Gromov-Witten potential associated to a TCFT", it says the pullback operation is not well-defined in simplicial chain, but it is defined for homotopy coinvariant, that's what I am studying.

Answer (score 2):

If you like complexes of vector spaces over the field with two elements, Lecture 2 in [this set of notes](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-917-topics-in-algebraic-topology-the-sullivan-conjecture-fall-2007/lecture-notes/) by Jacob Lurie has a nice treatment of homotopy coinvariants in that context.  Some technical complexity that arises in the topological category is avoided in the linear algebraic treatment.

Comment: Analogues of coinvariants for comodule algebras over Hopf algebras in model categorical setup is in a recent paper of Kathryn Hess on the arXiv.